# android tcp connection by name

Tags: android, networking, tcp, connection, hostname

I am trying to open a TCP connection from my android app to a server running on a Roving Networks WiFly. The WiFly appears on my router as hostname WiFly with an ip address of 192.168.1.4

When I connect using the ip address the connection opens correctly but if I connect using the hostname then I get an error thus:

Unable to Open host "wifly": No address associated with hostname

here is a fragment of code used:

```
    try 
    {
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("wifly");

        Log.d("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");

        //create a socket to make the connection with the server
        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

        .......
    }
```

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

You should check that the name is correct
You can list all your hosts using

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class ListNets {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws SocketException {
        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> nets = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        for (NetworkInterface netint : Collections.list(nets))
            displayInterfaceInformation(netint);
    }

    static void displayInterfaceInformation(NetworkInterface netint) throws SocketException {
        out.printf("Display name: %s\n", netint.getDisplayName());
        out.printf("Name: %s\n", netint.getName());
        Enumeration<InetAddress> inetAddresses = netint.getInetAddresses();
        for (InetAddress inetAddress : Collections.list(inetAddresses)) {
            out.printf("InetAddress: %s\n", inetAddress);
        }
        out.printf("\n");
     }
}
```

code taken from the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/nifs/listing.html)

and see what the actual name it identifies by, and use it.

Comment: I modified the code to run on my android but the results were this